# How can I have iOS Safari remember credentials for websites with HTTP(S) Basic Authentication?

Tags: ios, safari, password

I have a HTTPS website which is protected by [basic authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication). When I use Safari on macOS to access this website, it will store my credentials (in the Keychain). However, Safari on iOS (11.2.6) refuses to do so. I can click on the key icon on the top right of the keyboard, but it will show only credentials from  form-based websites (the same list as in macOS Safari -> Preferences -> Passwords). Is there any way I can force Safari on iOS to remember these basic authentication credentials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Safari does not support saving the credentials for basic authentication. That's why you're not asked to store it.

There are basically three work-arounds you can use:

The first is simply to create a bookmark that contains your credentials. Note that this should only be done if the credentials aren't "important" - like for example if this is one of those commercial web sites that allow anyone in that knows that this year's password is "2019" or something like that. Then you can create a bookmark for the URL like this:

```
http://user:pass@website.com/
```

When you open that bookmark, you'll not be asked for credentials, but will be logged in automatically.

If you require an ordinary amount of security regarding the saved credentials, you can instead use a different work around. On your device, access Settings and then Passwords & Accounts and then App & Website Passwords. At the top is a + icon that you can click to add your web site and the username and password.

Contrary to form based password authentication, the information you enter there will *not* be automatically filled out. However when you get the username/password popup, you have the option of clicking the little "key" icon to select the stored credentials.

The third possible work-around is to use a Mac logged in to the same iCloud account with Keychain enabled. Access the web site using Safari on the Mac, and you'll be able to store the credentials.

On the iOS device the credentials will not be automatically filled out, but you will be able to press the "lock" icon in the popup to allow choosing the credentials you've stored on the Mac.

Comment: Somehow (maybe due to an iOS update?) Safari on iOS now has access to the basic authentication credentials I entered on the Mac, and the option of clicking the little "key" icon to select the stored credentials now works for me (I swear it didn't work before). Thank you, at the very least for letting me try again :)

Comment: Yes, that is also a trick that can be used! - However you still cannot store it directly on the iOS device itself! Just added that trick to the answer :-)

Comment: new iOS can't find the key, do you know where it should show up? password are saved

Comment: Unfortunately sited saved to the Home Screen, don't seem to look up http auth passwords from the keychain.

Comment: Safari 16.4.1 on macOS 11 Big Sur luckily offers a ☑︎ Remember this password option for HTTP Basic AUTH which gets stored in Keychain.app — See [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459875/11510).

Comment: I answered the macOS specificsin detail separately at: [Where does macOS Safari persist the credentials of HTTP(S) Basic Authentication?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459912/)

Comment: Thanks @jksoegaard for encouraging me to do a clean separate Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 15, Settings > Passwords allows adding new entries by hand. You can fill in the website URL and the credentials here. The next time the basic auth dialog shows up, it will not, unfortunately, be pre-filled, but you will be presented with the Passwords button in your on-screen keyboards once you focus either of the username / password fields and from there you can pick the credentials. It's not completely straight-forward, but it is the best option I found, especially because some websites do not support reading the username and password from the URL, only from the HTTP header, so the trick with the bookmark with the credentials in it doesn't work everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

From [this Apple Support article:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203783#password)

> **If Safari won't save the password for one of the websites that you're using**
>
> Some websites request that passwords not be saved. Safari won't save
>   or autofill account names and passwords on those sites.

This is most likely the case here.

Also when you sign-in you for the first time you might have clicked "don't remember password"

Comment: No, that cannot be the case here. That feature allowing a web site to request passwords not be saved is NOT available for basic authentication.

Answer (score -1):

In Safari and Firefox it's not possible. Using the Brave browser it's possible to save the password. But it's sometimes buggy and keeps asking. Still better than Safari.