# Where does Safari persist the credentials of HTTP(S) Basic Authentication?

Tags: safari, password, keychain, authentication, http

- Some websites use [HTTP basic authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).
- How can you save the credentials of this kind of login in macOS Safari?
- Where does Safari persist the credentials?

Answer (score 4):

### macOS Safari's "☑︎ Remember this password" stores the credentials in the macOS Keychain

[image: MacOS 11 Big Sur with Safari 16.4.1 and its natively rendered HTTP Basic Authentication Login Screen. Sign in to example.com:443. Your login information will be sent securely. Username, Password, ☑︎ Remember this password, Cancel, Sign In. Stored in Keychain.app as Internet Password in the login keychain.]

- When you access a website which uses basic auth you get a login popup rendered by the web browser in its own visual style independent from the website.
- If you check the option ☑︎ Remember this password then the credentials gets stored in [Keychain.app](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac) with "Kind" being "Internet password" as opposed to "Web form password" (for stored passwords of normal web forms).

#### Further info regarding Keychain Sharing

- If you have iCloud Keychain sharing enabled, then this password syncs to iOS too.
- Did not test this myself but @Glorfindel [confirmed this to be the case](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319953/how-can-i-have-ios-safari-remember-credentials-for-websites-with-https-basic-a#comment466229_353781).